# .exe python app is NOT working on other machines that have no python installed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, dependency-management

I developed a python program and convert it into **.exe** file using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile master.py
```

After that I compressed it into a Zip-File and made an installer for the program using **NSIS**. Then, I uploaded it on to my Google Drive.

I switched to a new computer(has no python on it) and downloaded my program from Drive. I installed it on the machine and tried to run it. It worked because I was able to type some stuff. This program is NOT GUI based yet, it asks user to enter some stuff on the **Command Prompt**. Once user presses enter after typing an input, the program gives me an error such as: `ImportError: No module named selenium`

```
import os, time
import threading

status = True
while status:
# number of windows user want
num_of_win = input("How many screen would you like to open?\nNumber of screens [1-10]: ")
try:
    # convert it into an int
    num_of_win = int(num_of_win)
    # if number of windows is greater than 10
    if num_of_win > 10:
        print("Max number of screens you can have is 10. Please try again.")
    # if number of windows is equal to or less than 10
    elif num_of_win <= 10:
        # brake the loop
        status = False
        # open cmd windows num_of_win times
        for x in range(num_of_win):
            # this is path to index.py with parameter
            # its parameter is based on how many window we open in this for loop
            # /k = cmd stays after terminated
            # /c = cmd quits program completely
            path = "start cmd.exe /K python index.py " + str(x)
            threading.Thread(target=(os.system(path)))
            time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print("Something is wrong, try again!")
# if user enters letters
except ValueError:
    print("Please ONLY enter numbers")
```

I am guessing when I convert it into an **.exe** file, it did NOT load the dependent modules. My question is, **how do I make it so it runs on a machine that doesn't have python installed?**

NOTE: **master.exe** runs another python file **index.py**

Could it be that when I convert **master.py** into **.exe** it only loads dependencies that are written in the **master.py** and ignores **index.py** dependencies????

Comment: Try adding `import index` at the top of your script. Pyinstaller only looks at your imports, it's not smart enough to know that you are calling `python index.py`. You'll have to help it out there.

Comment: my index.py takes an argument so I cant really import the whole file. Is there a way to import only the modules from index.py?

Comment: Yes. import them right after os, time, threading.

Comment: Also, FYI if you put the code of index.py inside `if __name__ == '__main__': YOURCODE` then you can import index.py with it taking action.

Comment: now i am able to call my index.py after using `if __name__ == '__main__':` however, I still have the same issue when I open it on a different computer.

Comment: I would add the imports from the `index.py` file into the file you have in your question and rebuild it with pyinstaller. That would be the quickest route. It would be hard to re-inject the dependencies back into the pyinstaller file.

Comment: what do you mean "hard"? I tried but didn't work. should I uninstall pyinstaller and re install it?

Comment: Did you add the imports inside index.py to the script you have above? If so, could you update your question with the new code and any new error information. I don't have any way to duplicate your index.py or your environment.

Comment: I created a new python file called modules.py. It has all the modules I need for this project. master.py is importing * from modules.py. Tried it same error. I watched youtube video on TechWithTim and I followed the exact steps on how to turn .py --> .exe   I am still having the same issue.

Comment: 1. Add all imports from modules.py to master.py. 2. Could you add the text of the exact error? 3. Could you create a project on gihub with your code as it exists and link to it here?